# Azure Databricks - cost optimization

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-databricks

Considerable portion of my Azure Databrick's cost is being spent towards the storage account.

As per part "Azure databricks - cost optimization" steps, thought of storing data(i.e., delta tables, views, function etc) in mounted object storage (like Blob Storage) rather than in the DBFS root. So that I can use cold/archive tiers of Blob Storage to reduce cost.

Is this approach of Blob Storage rather than in the DBFS root is valid one?

Will it really save some cost spend towards the Azure Databricks storage?

Doing so, will have any performance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBFS Root in general [is not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/dbfs-root#educate-users-not-to-store-data-on-dbfs-root) for storing the production data for multiple reasons, like, no access outside, no control of the data lifecycle, etc., so you should use a separate storage accounts for that data.

But really, does most of your costs coming from the storage? Usually it's much smaller compared to the compute costs, etc.

Databricks field team recently released a very good [blog post](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/10/18/best-practices-cost-management-databricks.html) about cost management and optimization.

Comment: yes storage is second costliest  cost in our Azure Databrick usage. 
Virtual Machines :$10,656.25
Storage : $9,547.37

Comment: most probably because DBFS root storage account by default is GRS that is more expensive than other redundancy types. But it's still a lot of data there